# PysimpleGUI Calc not using function properly

Tags: python-3.x, calculator, pysimplegui

Hey everybody really scratching my head trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, it does not return any errors it just seems to skip over the calculating portion and prints the error message I included to indicate wrong user input, even though my user inputs are valid.

I've tried moving the if and defining statements about the variables around to see if that would work.

I know the variables are defined first above the calculate function and again in the function, the reason I have it this way is because otherwise I would get an error that they were undefined unless they came first above everything else.

```
#Weight Converter Calculator with GUI

import PySimpleGUI as sg

def h():
    h = height
def g():
    g = diameter
    if g == 9:
        diameter = .7
    if g == 11:
        diameter == .4
    if g == 11.5:
        diameter = .38    
def u():
    u = typeunit
    if u == ft:
        typeunit = 1
    if u == rl:
        typeunit = 50
    if u == pl:
        typeunit = 450    
def a():
    a = amount

def calc_weight(h, g, u, a):
    try:
        h, g, u, a = float(h), float(g), float(u), float(a)
        h = height
        a = amount
        g = diameter
        u = typeunit
        if g == 9:
            g = .7
        if g == 11:
            g = .4
        if g == 11.5:
            g = .38
        if u == 'ft':
            u = 1
        if u == 'rl':
            u = 50
        if u == 'pl':
            u = 450
        weight = h * g * u * a
        if weight >= 47001:
            standard = 'too heavy for a truck! '
        elif weight <= 47000:
            standard = 'will fit onto a truck! '
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return None
    else:
        return f'Weight: {weight}, {standard}'

layout = [
    
    [sg.Text('Please enter your desired Mesh Height, Gauge, Unit, Amount')],
    [sg.Text('Mesh Height in FT', size =(15, 1)), sg.Input(key = h)],
    [sg.Text('Gauge 9, 11, 11.5', size =(15, 1)), sg.Input(key = g)],
    [sg.Text('Unit "ft" for sq ft, "rl" for roll, and "pl" for pallet', size =(15, 3)), sg.Input(key = u)],
    [sg.Text('Amount', size =(15, 1)), sg.Input(key = a)],
    [sg.Text('', key='weight', size=(20, 2))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]
 
window = sg.Window('Chain Link Weight Calculator', layout)
sg.theme('DarkAmber') 
while True:
    event, value = window.Read()
    if event == 'Submit':
        weight = calc_weight(value[h], value[g], value[u], value[a],)
        if weight:
            window.Element('weight').Update(weight, text_color='white')
        else:
            window.Element('weight').Update('Input is incorrect! ', text_color='red')
    elif event == 'Cancel':
        break
    
window.Close()
```

Comment: Does your ```calc_weight``` function work standalone?  By this I mean, given a set of valid inputs to the function, does it produce the desired result?

Comment: Since the original `calc_weight` uses the `value[]` key from simplegui, how would I go about testing just that function on its own with user inputs? And you are probably right it's most likely an issue with the actual function @itprorh66 :p

Comment: I would start by just testing the function standalone and give it a series of valid input values as well as as some invalid values to ensure the function computes correctly.  If the function works correctly, then you can concentrate on the value[] function to ensure it is giving you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there're some issues

- Using function name as key of element, like `h`, `g`, `u` and `a` and those function useless
- Variables `height`, `amount`, `diameter` and `typeunit` not defined in function `calc_weight`
- Variables `h`, `g`, `u`, `a` reset in function `calc_weight`

Just demo script here,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def find_true(sequence):
    return sequence.index(True)

def calc_weight(values):
    try:
        h, a = float(values['h']), float(values['a'])
        index1 = find_true([values[key] for key in ('G1', 'G2', 'G3')])
        index2 = find_true([values[key] for key in ('U1', 'U2', 'U3')])
        g, u = guages[index1], units[index2]
        weight = h*g*u*a
        standard = 'too heavy for a truck!' if weight>= 47001 else 'will fit onto a truck!'
        result = f'Weight: {weight}, {standard}'
    except:
        result = None
    return result

guages = [0.7, 0.4, 0.38]
units  = [1, 50, 450]

sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter your desired Mesh Height, Gauge, Unit, Amount')],
    [sg.Text('Mesh Height in FT', size =(15, 1)), sg.Input(key='h')],
    [sg.Text('Gauge', size=(15, 1)),
     sg.Radio("9", 'Guage', size=(8, 1), key='G1', default=True),
     sg.Radio("11", 'Guage', size=(8, 1), key='G2'),
     sg.Radio("11.5", 'Guage', size=(8, 1), key='G3'),],
    [sg.Text('Unit', size=(15, 1)),
     sg.Radio("sq ft", 'Unit', size=(8, 1), key='U1', default=True),
     sg.Radio("roll", 'Unit', size=(8, 1), key='U2'),
     sg.Radio("pallet", 'Unit', size=(8, 1), key='U3'),],
    [sg.Text('Amount', size =(15, 1)), sg.Input(key='a')],
    [sg.Text('', key='weight', size=(45, 2))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Chain Link Weight Calculator', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.Read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        weight = calc_weight(values)
        if weight:
            window['weight'].update(weight, text_color='white')
        else:
            window['weight'].update('Input is incorrect!', text_color='white')

window.Close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this is awesome! I changed the values for gauges to accurately calculate their weight

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you assigned the gauge and unit values to an index and (called)? them using the radio? Thank you again for your time and help!

Comment: Just decide which value will be if which `sg.Radio` selected. Of course, you can also use `sg.Listbox` for specified labels/values.